# Writing a complex if condition in mongoose efficiently

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I have a set of conditions on my node app
where I am trying to implement the following if block -

```
if(((public==true)&&(varA=="something" || varB == "something")) || (public==false)&&(varA=="something" || varB == "something")&&(varc == "something"))
```

so what I tried to implement was something is -

```
db.foo.find({"$or":[{"$and":[{e:true},{"$or":[{d:"four"},{c:"seven"}]}]},{"$and":[{e:false},{a:"one"},{"$or":[{c:"three"},{c:"seven"}]}]}]})
```

Now, the variables varA,varB,varC are dynamic so they depend on the user's requests. so I can't write the query object as it is. I will have to write it in an array fashion

```
( like obj["$or][0]["$and"][e] = true; )
```

or something along these lines.

can I simplify my query more here ? or is there is a better and more efficient way of getting this required collection.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's examine your boolean condition. It helps to write it out on multiple lines using indentation. Writing it on one line makes it nigh incomprehensible.

```
(public==true && (varA=="something" || varB == "something")) 
|| 
(public==false)
&& 
(varA=="something" || varB == "something") 
&& 
(varc == "something")
```

Let's simplify this. Let `P` be `public==true` and let `A`, `B`, `C` be the obvious conditions. I'm not sure if all the `"something"`'s are meant to be all different values or all the same or what, so I'm going to assume that for a fixed value of *, `var*` conditions use the same `"something"`. Then the condition is

```
(P && (A || B)) 
|| 
~P
&& 
(A || B) 
&& 
C
```

This is a bit goofy so let's try to simplify further. The easiest way to do this is to use the symbol `+` for or `||` and `*` for and `&&` since the rules for boolean algebra work like the rules for `+` and `*` in this way. Not is `~`. I'll start using juxtaposition for `*`, too.

```
(P * (A + B)) + ~P * (A + B) * C =
PA + PB + (~P)AC + (~P)BC =
A(P + (~P)C) + B(P + (~P)C)
```

OK. Let's think about this condition. Clearly, we need one of `A` and `B` to be true. Then we need `P + (~P)C` to be true. It's pointless to check `~P` in the condition, since if `P` is true we win, else we need `C`, so we can simplify the condition to

```
A(P + C) + B(P + C)
```

As a query object this looks like

```
{
    "$or" : [
        {
            varA : "something",
            "$or" : [
                { "public" : true },
                { varC : "something" }
            ]
        },
        {
            varB : "something",
            "$or" : [
                { "public" : true },
                { varC : "something" }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I would create this object in Javascript as follows:

```
var myQuery = {
    "$or" : [
        {
            "$or" : [
                { "public" : true },
                { }
            ]
        },
        {
            "$or" : [
                { "public" : true },
                { }
            ]
        },
    ]
};
myQuery["$or"][0][varA] = "something";
myQuery["$or"][1][varB] = "something";
myQuery["$or"][0]["$or"][1][varC] = "something";
myQuery["$or"][1]["$or"][1][varC] = "something";
```

I'd appreciate if you and any other generous SO readers would check over this, as obviously there have been many opportunities for errors in the reasoning and symbolic manipulation.